# Complex Numbers: A Basic Manipulation

Tags: complex-numbers

> $$ z = e^{i \phi} \tan \Bigg (\frac{\theta}{2} \Bigg).  $$

What is,

> $$ \frac{|z|}{1 + |z|^2} $$

Comment: What have you tried? Knowing that $|ab| = |a|~ |b|$, what can you say about $|z|$?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $\theta\space\wedge\phi\space\in\mathbb{R}$ and knowing that $\cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1$

$$\left|e^{\phi i}\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|=\left|e^{\phi i}\right|\left|\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|=$$
$$\left|\cos(\phi)+\sin(\phi)i\right|\left|\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|=$$
$$\sqrt{\cos^2(\phi)+\sin^2(\phi)}\cdot\left|\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|=$$
$$1\cdot\left|\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|=\left|\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|$$

So, we get:

$$\frac{|z|}{1+|z|^2}=\frac{\left|\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|}{1+\left|\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|^2}=\frac{\left|\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|}{\left|\sec\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|^2}$$

Comment: And simplifying this is not an option because?

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, $\mathrm e^{i\phi}$ denotes the complex numbers of module $1$, hence
$$\lvert z\rvert=\lvert\mathrm e^{i\phi}\rvert\Bigl\lvert\tan\frac\theta2\Bigr\rvert=\Bigl\lvert\tan\frac\theta2\Bigr\rvert,$$
so that
$$\frac{\lvert z\rvert}{1+\lvert z\rvert^2}=\frac{\Bigl\lvert\tan\dfrac\theta2\Bigr\rvert}{1+\tan^2\dfrac\theta2}=\cos^2\frac\theta2\,\Bigl\lvert\tan\frac\theta2\Bigr\rvert=\Bigl\lvert\sin\frac\theta2\cos\frac\theta2\Bigr\rvert=\tfrac12\rvert\sin\theta\rvert.$$

Comment: I think you mean $\left| \sin \frac{\theta}{2} \cos \frac{\theta}{2} \right|$ on your last line. Or, equivalently, $\frac{|\sin \theta|}{2}$.

Comment: You've made a mistake because: $$\frac{\left|\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|}{1+\left|\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|^2}\ne\left|\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\right|$$

Comment: @Clive Newstead: Actually I had forgotten $\cos^{\color{red}2}\dfrac\theta2$. Fixed. Thank you for pointing the error.

Comment: @Jan Eerland:  I   forgot  $\cos^{\color{red}2}\dfrac\theta2$. Fixed. Thank you for pointing the error.

Comment: @Bernard You're welcome, great (+1).